# Why both image created from np.ones and np.zeros shows black blank image while combining both gives black and white mixed image as expected?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, grayscale

What i mean that:

1. I expect to see blank black image when i create image using np.ones which i see that result.
2. I expect to see black and white mixed image when i create random array consist either 0 or 1 which i see that result.
3. I expect to see blank white image when i create image using np.zeros which i still see blank black image.

Here are my codes:

```
def display_img(img):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
```

1.) Below code gives black image as expected.

```
black = np.zeros((600,600),dtype=np.int8)
black
display_img(black)
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

2.) Below code gives mixed image black image with white noises as expected since some values are 1 now.

```
white_noise = np.random.randint(low=0,high=2,size=(600,600))
white_noise
display_img(white_noise)
array([[0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0]])
```

3.) Below code gives black image but i expect to see white

```
white = np.ones((600,600),dtype=np.int8)
white
white

array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
display_img(white)
```

Comment: I think thats the case when we have 3 channel, but  arrays here only have 2 dimension. And also i see white for all 1 values for the case number 2 as i expected.

Comment: ı also tried  white = np.random.randint(255,256,(600,600)) which creates and array full of 255 values. and when i display it, result is still blank black image.

Comment: I tried: white_noise = np.random.randint(low=255,high=256,size=(600,600),dtype=np.uint8) still returns black image

Comment: you should multiply white with 255 --> np.ones((600,600),dtype=np.int8)*255

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working if instead of `ax.imshow(img,cmap='gray')` you code `ax.imshow(img,cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=1)`.

You can see why [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) :

vmin and vmax define the data range that the colormap covers.